# Getting Wrong value of image while retrieving from Sqlite DB in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite

Getting wrong value from DB while retrieving image Blob value from sqlite DB in iOS.I store image blob value in DB but when i try to get the value it give me extra number of bytes.Any please help me.

Insert value using below method:

```
{
 NSData * compressimagestream = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageview.image, 0.5);
 sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO IMAGE ('Image') VALUES ('%@')",compressimagestream];

 sqlite3_stmt* statement;


 if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
 {
    sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1,[field2 bytes],[field2 length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    sqlite3_step(statement);
    NSLog(@"Update %@",field2);
    return TRUE;
 }
 else
 {
   NSLog(@"Update Fail");
   return  FALSE;
 }
}
```

The insert code is working correctly and store wright amount of bytes as i get from UIImageJPEGRepresentation method.

I am retrieving value from below method:

```
  {
  NSData *find = NULL;
  sqlite3_stmt *statement;
  sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"select * from IMAGE"];
 const char *query_stmt = [sql UTF8String];

 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
 {
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {

    NSData *content = [[NSData alloc]
                   initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 1)
                   length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 1)];
        find = content;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Not found");
    }
    sqlite3_reset(statement);
 }
 return find;
 }
```

Thanks in Advance, sorry for my english.

Comment: How many fields are there in your table ?

Comment: I have only two value in which 1 is auto increment and 1 is image

Comment: BTW, if the image is sizable (e.g. more than 100kb), you should note that SQLite is notoriously inefficient in storing large blobs. If it's a tiny thumbnail image, the performance hit is modest, but if it's large, you may see a performance hit. Often people will store large images in the Documents folder, and only save the path of the image file in the database.

Comment: FYI, you are also not calling `sqlite3_finalize` when your insert routine finishes, which can result in a leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insertion into the database is not quite right. Your SQL should be:

```
sql = @"INSERT INTO IMAGE ('Image') VALUES (?)";
```

You have to use the `?` placeholder for the `sqlite3_bind_blob` to succeed. I'd wager that if you checked the return code from the `sqlite3_bind_blob`, it is not currently returning `SQLITE_OK` (and possibly that the result from `sqlite3_step` is not `SQLITE_DONE`, either).

Always check the return codes from all of your SQLite calls, and if you don't get `SQLITE_OK` and `SQLITE_DONE` (from `sqlite3_bind_blob` and `sqlite3_step`, respectively), you should log `sqlite3_errmsg(db)`, and SQLite will probably provide some informative error messages.

Likewise, if the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails, you'd want to log the error message, e.g.

```
NSLog(@"Update Fail: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
```

---

By the way, the [`sqlite3_column_xxx()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) functions use a zero-based index (unlike [`sqlite3_bind_xxx()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) calls that use a one-based index). So you probably want:

```
NSData *find = nil;
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
sql = @"select IMAGE from IMAGE";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    int rc;

    if ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0)
                                                 length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0)];
        find = content;
    }
    else if (rc == SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"Not found");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"step error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}

return find;
```

Also, note that I'm calling `sqlite3_finalize`, not `sqlite3_reset`.

Comment: @SyedSharjeelAli That is unlikely. More likely you're inserting a string hex representation of your binary data (e.g. a string that looks like `@"<wwxxyyzz wwxxyyzz ...>"`). You're building a SQL with `stringWithFormat` of an `NSData` (which will insert the `description` string, not the binary data). And why do a `sqlite3_bind_blob` if you have no `?` placeholder? You're so close (`sqlite3_bind_blob` is the right idea), but you need to use the `?` placeholder in your SQL, and you want to reference `compressimagestream` in your `sqlite3_bind_blob`, not `field2` (what is `field2`, anyway?).